# how to count relationships from inital query

Tags: optimization, neo4j, cypher

Hi I would like to make a query from a query (if that makes any sense)

My original solution is

```
PROFILE MATCH (q:Question)-[:TAGGED]-> (:Tag {name:"python"}) 
CALL{ WITH q ]
MATCH (q:Question)-[:TAGGED]-> (t:Tag) 
WITH q, count(t) as c 
RETURN c} 
RETURN max(c)
```

The aim is to find all the questions `q` with the relationship `TAGGED` that is python. From the `q` nodes that we get the second objective is to count the number of relationships `TAGGED` that they have. The goal is to find the maximum amount of `TAGGED` relationships a question `q` can have. The problem is that this is not optimized enough as I am trying to limit the db hits. Another idea was the following

```
MATCH (:Tag {name: 'python'}) <-[:TAGGED]- (q:Question)-[:TAGGED]->(t: Tag) 
WITH q, count(t) + 1 AS c 
RETURN max(c)
```

In the first case, I tried to find first the questions that had at least the tag python and then pipeline the questions to count the number of relationships the filtered questions had but this seemed to be worse compared to the second query.

In the second query I had a problem with an expansion when I tried `PROFILE` and at the stage `(q)-[anon_2:TAGGED]->(t)` I take on too many db hits.

I'm confused as to how my first query doesn't work as well as the second.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following query:

```
MATCH (q:Question)
WHERE (q)-[:TAGGED]-> (:Tag {name:"python"})
WITH q,size((q)-[:TAGGED]->()) AS count
RETURN max(count)
```

Comment: I tried using the command but unfortunately it failed since it exceeded memory limits

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this one:

```
PROFILE MATCH (q:Question)-[:TAGGED]-> (t:Tag) 
WITH q, collect(t) AS tags
WHERE ANY(tag IN tags WHERE tag.name = 'python')
WITH q, size(tags) AS tagSize
RETURN max(tagSize)
```